# JavaScript regex to split camel case string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string, regex-group

I have been trying to split a string with space when camel case happens. This is so far I can:

```
CamelCaseSplit = (inputString) => {
    const f = str => str.match(/^[A-Z]?[^A-Z]*|[A-Z][^A-Z]*/g).join(' 
 <CAMEL> ');
    return f(inputString);
}
```

It can handle string likes "camelCase", "simple", "number1Case2".

But fails for "ABCWordDEF" and gives me "A  B  C  Word  D  E  F" instead of "ABC  Word  DEF".

Also the output of "abcDeF123" should be "abc  De  F123"

How to properly implement splitting into camel case?

Answer (score 0):

You use Lodash's `_.words()` (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#words) and say

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

const camelCaseToWords = s => _.words(s).join(' ');
```

Comment: It does not preverse space in the input string i.e. if I feed "  " it will make it ""

Comment: It also split on number

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
(?<=[a-z\d])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])
```

To replace with a space. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oQgspb/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=[a-z\d])(?=[A-Z])` - a location between a lowercase letter or a digit, and a an uppercase letter
- `|` - or
- `(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])` - a location between an uppercase letter and a sequence of an uppercase letter + a lowercase letter.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
CamelCaseSplit = (inputString) => {
    const f = str => str.replace(/(?<=[a-z\d])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])/g, ' ');
    return f(inputString);
}
const texts = ['camelCase','simple','number1Case2','ABCWordDEF','abcDeF123'];
for (const s of texts) {
  console.log(s, '->', CamelCaseSplit(s))
}
```